# How to minimize the window in mac using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need a functionality for minimizing a window from the menu.

I have searched related this and found `-miniaturize` method for minimizing from apple documentation but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: `miniaturize` is a function of `NSWindow` have you tried running it on the window you want to minimise? What code did you use> What was the result?

Comment: ... so first we need a reference to the window.

Comment: I did not know how to write function to minimise @Fogmeister

Comment: @ trojanfoe - yes. i have a reference for my window

Comment: But you don't know how to call a method on an Objective-C object?

Comment: @IOSdeveloper you don't have to write the function. You just call it. `[window miniaturize];`.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fogmeister you should write an answer and IOS developer should accept it and upvote it. :-)

Comment: @daredevil done :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `miniaturize` doesn't need to be written. It is there for you to call.

```
NSWindow *window = //the window you want to minimise.
[window miniaturize];
```

This will minimise the window.

Comment: While correct, it's ridiculous that you have to explain how to do something so basic.  I am certain the OP will many more questions...

Comment: @trojanfoe I agree. I guess the question either needs answering or closing. Is it possible to close a question because it is too simple? :-D

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know if "too broad" covers it though. Checking out meta :D

Comment: @trojanfoe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42311/questions-which-are-too-simple-is-this-one-reasonable I'm going to leave it. It may be simple but it fixes an inherent misunderstanding of the documentation. The OP found the method just didn't realise that it was something to be called, not written.

Answer (score 1):

When I used

> [window miniaturize];

The window did not close, I also had a warning in that line stating,

> Instance method '-miniaturize' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

When I change the code to

> NSWindow *window = //the window you want to minimise.
>
> [ window miniaturize: self ] ;

The window got miniaturized and also the warning went off.

Comment: That's because the method signature is "miniaturize:"  (with a colon on the end) not "miniaturize". You need to pass a sender ID argument, even a nil one will do.